# Likelihood maximization in R

Tags: r, optimization

In R, I wrote a log-likelihood function containing two recursive calculation. The log-likelihood function works properly (it gives answer for known values of parameters), but when I try to maximize it using `optim()`, it takes too much time. How can I optimize the code? Thanks in advance for ideas.

This is the log-likelihood function for a markov regime switching model with a dependence structure using copula functions.

[image: log-likelihood function]

Named `g` in the for loop:

[image: g in the codes]

Named `p` in the for loop:

[image: p in the codes]

Named `f` in the codes:

[image: f in the codes]

Some data:

```
u <- cbind(rt(100,10),rt(100,13))
```

`f` function:

```
f=function(u,p,e1,e2){
     s=diag(2);s[1,2]=p
     ff=dcopula.gauss(cbind(pt(u[,1],e1),pt(u[,2],e2)),Sigma=s)*dt(u[,1],e1)*dt(u[,2],e2)
     return(ff)
  }
```

log-likelihood function:

```
loglik=function(x){
  p11<-x[1];p12<-x[2];p21<-x[3];p22<-x[4];p31<-x[5];p32<-x[6];r<-x[7];a1<-x[8];a2<-x[9];s<-x[10];b1<-x[11];b2<-x[12];t<-x[13];c1<-x[14];c2<-x[15]
  p1=c(numeric(nrow(u)));p2=c(numeric(nrow(u)));p3=c(numeric(nrow(u)))
  g=c(numeric(nrow(u)))
  p1_0=.3
  p2_0=.3
  g[1]<-(p1_0*f(u,r,a1,a2)[1])+(p2_0*f(u,s,b1,b2)[1])+((1-(p1_0+p2_0))*f(u,t,c1,c2)[1])
  p1[1]<-((p1_0*p11*f(u,r,a1,a2)[1])+(p2_0*p21*f(u,r,a1,a2)[1])+((1-(p1_0+p2_0))*p31*f(u,r,a1,a2)[1]))/g[1]
  p2[1]<-((p1_0*p12*f(u,s,b1,b2)[1])+(p2_0*p22*f(u,s,b1,b2)[1])+((1-(p1_0+p2_0))*p32*f(u,s,b1,b2)[1]))/g[1]
  p3[1]<-((p1_0*(1-(p11+p12))*f(u,t,c1,c2)[1])+(p2_0*(1-(p21+p22))*f(u,t,c1,c2)[1])+((1-(p1_0+p2_0))*(1-(p31+p32))*f(u,t,c1,c2)[1]))/g[1]
  for(i in 2:nrow(u)){
    g[i]<-(p1[i-1]*p11*f(u,r,a1,a2)[i])+(p1[i-1]*p12*f(u,s,b1,b2)[i])+(p1[i-1]*(1-(p11+p12))*f(u,t,c1,c2)[i])+
      (p2[i-1]*p21*f(u,r,a1,a2)[i])+(p2[i-1]*p22*f(u,s,b1,b2)[i])+(p2[i-1]*(1-(p21+p22))*f(u,t,c1,c2)[i])+
      (p3[i-1]*p31*f(u,r,a1,a2)[i])+(p3[i-1]*p32*f(u,s,b1,b2)[i])+(p3[i-1]*(1-(p31+p32))*f(u,t,c1,c2)[i])
    p1[i]<-((p1[i-1]*p11*f(u,r,a1,a2)[i])+(p1[i-1]*p12*f(u,s,b1,b2)[i])+(p1[i-1]*(1-(p11+p12))*f(u,t,c1,c2)[i]))/g[i]
    p2[i]<-((p2[i-1]*p21*f(u,r,a1,a2)[i])+(p2[i-1]*p22*f(u,s,b1,b2)[i])+(p2[i-1]*(1-(p21+p22))*f(u,t,c1,c2)[i]))/g[i]
    p3[i]<-((p3[i-1]*p31*f(u,r,a1,a2)[i])+(p3[i-1]*p32*f(u,s,b1,b2)[i])+(p3[i-1]*(1-(p31+p32))*f(u,t,c1,c2)[i]))/g[i]
  }
  return(-sum(log(g)))
}
```

Optimization:

```
library(QRM)
library(copula)
start=list(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,9,7,-1,10,13,1,6,4)
##
optim(start,loglik,lower=c(rep(0,6),-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1),
  upper=c(rep(1,6),1,Inf,Inf,1,Inf,Inf,1,Inf,Inf),
  method="L-BFGS-B") -> fit
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a question for Stack-Overflow.

Something that springs to my mind is:

1. Define a vector containing the values `f(.,.,.,.)` in order to avoid doing `k*nrow(u)` evaluations of the same function and simply call those entries of interest.
2. It seems like the loop could be replaced by matrix and/or vector products. However, without further information it is unclear what the code is doing and it would take eons to extract this information from the code.

Comment: Thanks Nephilim, I applied your first advice. 
The question edited and some information added.